# Jasmine Spec Helpers not loaded

Tags: typescript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write my unit tests with Jasmine and Karma in a Typescript environment.

I have installed karma, karma-typescript, karma-jasmine, jasmine and jasmine-ts.

I have added a custom tsconfig.json to the `spec` directory and use it in the karma-typescript settings.

Generally, my tests are working, however, it doesn't execute my spec helpers.

**Is there something I am missing for it to execute my spec helpers?**

---

For your reference, here is my configuration:

`karma.conf.js`:

```js
    module.exports = function (config) {
        config.set({
    
            // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
            basePath: '',
    
    
            // frameworks to use
            // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
            frameworks: ['jasmine', "karma-typescript"],
    
    
            // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
            files: [
                "spec/helpers/chai.ts",
                {pattern: "src/**/*.ts"},
                {pattern: "spec/**/*.ts"}
            ],
    
    
            // list of files to exclude
            exclude: [],
    
    
            // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
            // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
            preprocessors: {
                "src/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"],
                "spec/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
            },
    
            karmaTypescriptConfig: {
                bundlerOptions: {
                    entrypoints: /\.spec\.ts$/
                },
                tsconfig: "./spec/tsconfig.json",
                coverageOptions: {
                    exclude: [/\.(d|spec|test)\.tsx?/, /\/spec\//]
                }
            },
            specReporter: {
                maxLogLines: 3,             // limit number of lines logged per test
                suppressErrorSummary: true, // do not print error summary
                suppressFailed: false,      // do not print information about failed tests
                suppressPassed: false,      // do not print information about passed tests
                suppressSkipped: true,      // do not print information about skipped tests
                showSpecTiming: false,      // print the time elapsed for each spec
                failFast: false              // test would finish with error when a first fail occurs.
            },
            // test results reporter to use
            // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
            // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
            reporters: ['spec', "karma-typescript", "kjhtml"],
    
    
            // web server port
            port: 9876,
    
    
            // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
            colors: true,
    
    
            // level of logging
            // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
            logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    
    
            // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
            autoWatch: true,
    
    
            // start these browsers
            // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
            browsers: ['Chrome'],
    
    
            // Continuous Integration mode
            // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
            singleRun: false,
    
            // Concurrency level
            // how many browser should be started simultaneous
            concurrency: Infinity
        })
    }
```

`jasmine.json` (Although I have the feeling that it isn't used):

```js
    {
      "spec_dir": "spec",
      "spec_files": [
        "**/*[sS]pec.ts"
      ],
      "helpers": [
        "helpers/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
      "random": false,
      "reporters": [
        {
          "name": "jasmine-spec-reporter#SpecReporter"
        }
      ],
      "project": "./spec/"
    }
```

`tsconfig.json` in root:

```js
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
          "es6",
          "dom",
          "es2015.promise"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types",
          "typings"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*"
      ]
    }
```

`tsconfig.json` in spec folder:

```js
    {
      "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
          "../node_modules/@types",
          "typings"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "./**/*",
        "../src/**/*"
      ]
    }
```

---

`spec/helpers/chai.ts` is the spec helper that karma is not executing.

The content of that file is:

```
import * as chai from "chai";
import chaiThings = require("chai-things");
import chaiInterface = require("chai-interface");

chai.should();
chai.use(chaiThings);
chai.use(chaiInterface);
```

---

Please see https://github.com/dhilgarth/mjt for a self contained example.

Comment: How do you run your tests ? What is the exact command line ?

Comment: `karma start --single-run` or `karma start`

Comment: Is it definitely loading your chai.ts helper? Tell Karma to open a browser you can interact with, e.g. Chrome, Firefox etc... and once the browser had loaded the karma runner, pop open the dev tools and check to see the test runner is loading the chair helper on the network panel. I notice you explicitly state thar Karma isn't executing your helper. Just want to confirm that it's at least loading it first.

Comment: @DanielLane: Yes, it is loading the compiled version - i.e. the js version - of the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the problem here was that the Karma config had a minor mis-configuration that's easily missed.

The files node of the Karma config is completely valid and matches all the test specs you want Karma to load.

The karmaTypescriptConfig node of the karma config applies an extra filter on the files loaded by Karma, in your case you're only including files loaded by karma that match .spec.ts files.

The bundler couldn't find the helper specs as they didn't match the regex pattern: .spec.ts, even though they're specified under the files node. So the helper scripts were being excluded from the test after they'd been loaded.

The fix to this is to either remove the karmaTypescriptConfig node, reconfigure it to match the helper explicitly or rename the helper to be matched by the given matcher.

I've removed it from the below example. The bundler will bundle all files loaded by Karma by default.

The official documentation states

> karmaTypescriptConfig.bundlerOptions.entrypoints - A regex filtering which files loaded by Karma should be executed in a test run, for example only filenames ending with ".spec.ts": /.spec.ts$/.
>   This setting can be used to make sure the specs have finished setting up the test environment before other code starts requiring modules, which otherwise could lead to subtle bugs caused by race conditions.
>   Defaults to all files, /.*/.

Hope this helps!

`karma.conf.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (config) {
 config.set({

  // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
  basePath: '',

  // frameworks to use
  // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
  frameworks: ['jasmine', "karma-typescript"],

  // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
  files: [
   "spec/helpers/helper.ts", {
    pattern: "src/**/*.ts"
   }, {
    pattern: "spec/**/*.ts"
   }
  ],

  client: {
   clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
  },

  // list of files to exclude
  exclude: [],

  // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
  // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
  preprocessors: {
   "spec/helpers/helper.ts": ["karma-typescript"],
   "src/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"],
   "spec/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
  },

  // test results reporter to use
  // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
  // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
  reporters: ['progress', "karma-typescript"],

  // web server port
  port: 9876,

  // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
  colors: true,

  // level of logging
  // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
  logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

  // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
  autoWatch: true,

  // start these browsers
  // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
  browsers: ['Chrome'],

  // Continuous Integration mode
  // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
  singleRun: false,

  // Concurrency level
  // how many browser should be started simultaneous
  concurrency: Infinity
 })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only viable options is to store helpers in separate forlder, compile them with `tsc` and add as `.js` files to karma.config

Check this PR for steps to make it work: https://github.com/dhilgarth/mjt/pull/1/files

```
    files: [
        {pattern: "spec/helpers/*.js"},
        {pattern: "src/**/*.ts"},
        {pattern: "spec/**/*.ts"}
    ],

    client:{
      jasmine: {
        helpers: [
          "spec/helpers/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, but, no, that doesn't help. The helpers directory is a sub directory of the directory that contains the `tsconfig.json` and is therefore included in the `"./**/*"` glob

Comment: Try to load helpers in karma config, files section, after chai helper and prior to src and specs

Comment: Did that as well. No difference. Also, it is already included in the glob starting with `spec`

Comment: let's try another way, how it works for me: karma config loads `test.ts` (https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/6026a8c9360009718b0c0e358a85e48a8569d442/karma.conf.js#L21) , `test.ts` loads matcher prior to everything else (https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/7c87162d6949ca57460011973bf38938c9805477/scripts/test.ts#L15) ,where matchers is (https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/7cab3a42673ea353c1d02374f2bd2349d31319e4/scripts/matchers.ts)

Comment: I tried to mimik that, but it still didn't work. A big difference is that I am using `karma-typescript` and not the angular cli as preporcessor

Comment: ok, let's try to brut force this, import one of your helpers to `spec/helpers/chai.ts` and check, does it work or not

Comment: if it will work, then you can create `helpers/index.ts` and import it in karma config, just after `chai.ts` helper

Comment: Not sure I understand. Why the index.ts? What difference will it bring?

Comment: try to import one of your helpers in `spec/helpers/chai.ts` and check does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I don't understand what difference this should bring. Why should `custom.ts` work if `chai.ts` doesn't? And also, again, both helper files should already be included in the last pattern anyway.

Comment: it's not only about being included, it's about the order of being included

Comment: Sure, but I already included chai.ts at the beginning as you can see. And it is not working, so why should a second file help? (I tested it, and it doesn't help, so I am not just discussing it hypothetically.)

Comment: please add to Question, that `chai.ts` is your custom helpers, which are not working... cuz I thought it's working

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154697/discussion-between-valorkin-and-daniel-hilgarth).